# Prove that a function is $L^p(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral

There is a specific criterion for proving that a function $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ as well as proving it by definition ?

Furthermore, is correct to imply that:
If $|\ f|^{\ p}$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$, and $$\lim_{t \to \pm \infty} |\ f(t)\ |^{\ p} = 0 $$ Then $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Basically everything comes down to the definition.  There are various ways of proving that an improper integral converges.
2. Does the improper integral of a continuous function converge if the integrand goes to $0$ at $\infty$?

Comment: Ok, I understand. For example the integral $$ \int_1^{+\infty} \frac{1}{x}\ dx $$ doesn't converge even if the function is 0 at $\infty$. But then I must evaluate the integral for proving that $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ every time ?

Comment: You don't need to evaluate the integral, just show that it is finite.  A useful strategy is to find $g \in L^1$ such that $|f|^p \le g$.

Comment: Can you please give me a reference for this result ?

Comment: What result?  The [comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test) for integrals?

Comment: Maybe I wasnt'clear. I mean the condition in which, if I use the comparison test for improper integral ,and I can prove that the improper integral is finite, I can imply that also the Lebesgue integral is finite.

Answer (score 1):

No. Positively not. A continuous function on $\Bbb R$ that tends to zero at infinity need not be in $L^p(\Bbb R)$; saying it's in $L^p$ says something about how fast it tends to infinity.

For example consider $$f(t)=\frac1{(1+|t|)^{1/p}}.$$

On a related note, a continuous function that lies in $L^p(\Bbb R)$ need not tend to zero at infinity, although here I don't think one can write down a single simple formula for an example.

Comment: Try $f(t) = |\cos(t)|^{|t|^3}$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Nice one. (Not that I've verified that works, nor that I intend to do so - it's certainly clear that something like $|\cos(t)|^{f(t)})$ gives an example if $f$ blows up fast enough. Duh.)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to David C. Ullrich's answer, we can construct a continuous $L^p$ function which doesn't vanish at infinity as follows. For each $n$, let $f_n$ be $0$ outside of $(n,n+2^{-n})$, $1$ at $n+2^{-(n+1)}$ and linearly interpolated in between. Explicitly, we have
$$f_n(x)=[1-2^{n+1}|n+2^{-(n+1)}-x|]\mathbf 1_{(n,n+2^{-n})}(x).$$
Now let $f(x):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$. It is not hard to show that this series converges pointwise to a continuous function and $f\in L^p(\mathbb R)$ for all $1\le p\le\infty$, however $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ does not exist.